# How to configure support for multiple active profiles with priority

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

is possible configure configure support to multiple spring profiles? For instance:

we have profiles to separate environments like dev and prod. We have linked some configuration of beans with that profile. Now we want add new profiles which configure database, like local-db, docker-db, and so on.

These profiles can be combined, like `dev & docker-db`, or `dev & local-db`. What is best practice for multiple profiles like this? Now we have configuration files like  `application.properties`, `application-dev.properties`, `application-prod.properties`

I was thinking about adding new `application-docker.properties` for instance, where will be configuration only for different datasource. Is possible to tell spring when match 2 application properties, set higher priority second one or how to handle it?